# _cmd value inside C functions

Tags: objective-c, cmd, selector, introspection

What's the value of `_cmd` variable when I access it from C-style function's body?

Is it defined inside Objective-C methods *only*?

P.S. This question may originate from my non-understanding of what `_cmd` is. I would greatly appreciate if someone provided me with a good explanation source.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's for Objective-C methods only, so you can't access it. The first two parameters passed to all Objective-C methods are `self` and `_cmd`, then whatever other arguments the actual method takes. Since neither `self` nor `_cmd` are passed to regular C functions, you can't access them.

There's nothing particularly magic about either variable.

Comment: For reference: [Objective-C methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). Note that any C function that takes an `id` and `SEL` as its first two arguments can be used as a method implementation. Similarly, any method implementation is a C function that takes an `id` and `SEL` as its first two arguments.

Comment: To be extra clear, `_cmd` is an `SEL` -- the method selector for the Objective-C method. "A method selector is a C string that has been registered (or 'mapped') with the Objective-C runtime."

Answer (score 25):

The major use of the `_cmd`  function is to get the method name in which it is called.

The use of the _cmd with some other functions has been written below.

```
NSLog(@"<%@:%@:%d>", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __LINE__);
```

Instead of above line you can also use PrettyFunction

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod) for further explanations.

```
func class_addMethod(_ cls: AnyClass!, 
                   _ name: Selector!, 
                   _ imp: IMP!, 
                   _ types: UnsafePointer<Int8>!) -> Bool
```

**imp**:

```
A function which is the implementation of the new method. The function must take at least two arguments—self and _cmd.
```